# Java program running in eclipse but not in command prompt

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, hibernate-search

I've got a little project built by me, which is written in Java using Hibernate 5, Hibernate Search 5.5, Log4j2 and accesses PostgreSQL's 3 databases (2 of them validating their metadata and another one creating content).

The issue is that it's a quite strange behaviour, which I'm trying to explain to all of you.

When I launch the Main class in Eclipse, the program runs well, as intended. The problem comes when I generate the JAR and execute it using the command shell... Here it's the stack [trace](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=3kdquD5q).

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.SearchFactoryReference]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:184)
        at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.sessionFactoryCreated(HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.java:86)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:541)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
        at dao.paradasws.ServiceDaoParadasWs.getSessionFactory(ServiceDaoParadasWs.java:89)
        at dao.AbstractDao.<init>(AbstractDao.java:27)
        at dao.paradasws.ServiceDaoParadasWs.<init>(ServiceDaoParadasWs.java:36)
        at tasks.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:49)
```

The method in which I'm getting the exceptions is the following:

```
@Override
protected SessionFactory getSessionFactory() throws HibernateException {

    if(getFactory() == null){
        // Configuramos hibernate:
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        // Dialecto PostgreSQL:
        //cfg.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect");
        // Dialecto Postgis:
        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect");
        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.postgresql.Driver");

        // Linux Server
        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database");
        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "postgres");
        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "postgres");

        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        cfg.setProperty("show_sql", "true");
        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.pool_size", "5000");

        // C3p0 connection pool
//      cfg.setProperty("connection.provider_class", "org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider");
//      cfg.setProperty("c3p0.min_size", "7");
//      cfg.setProperty("c3p0.max_size", "1000");
//      cfg.setProperty("c3p0.timeout", "1000");
//      cfg.setProperty("c3p0.idle_test_period", "2000");
//      cfg.setProperty("c3p0.preferredTestQuery", "select 1;");
//      cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.release_mode", "after_transaction");

        // Hibernate search:
        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.search.default.directory_provider", "filesystem");
        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.search.default.indexBase", "indexLucene");

        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");

        cfg.addAnnotatedClass(OperadorWS.class);
        cfg.addAnnotatedClass(ParadaWS.class);

        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
        builder.applySettings(cfg.getProperties());
        StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = builder.build();
        setFactory(cfg.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry));

        setStats(getFactory().getStatistics());
        getStats().setStatisticsEnabled(true);

    }

    return super.getFactory();

}
```

Just in case it's needed, I post my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>autom</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- NOTE: We don't need a groupId specification because the group is
                     org.apache.maven.plugins ...which is assumed by default.
                 -->
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <classpathMavenRepositoryLayout>true</classpathMavenRepositoryLayout>
                            <mainClass>tasks.Main</mainClass>
                            <addExtensions>true</addExtensions>
                            <classpathLayoutType>repository</classpathLayoutType>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>

                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <classpathMavenRepositoryLayout>true</classpathMavenRepositoryLayout>
                            <mainClass>tasks.Main</mainClass>
                            <addExtensions>true</addExtensions>
                            <classpathLayoutType>repository</classpathLayoutType>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- or whatever version you use -->
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <commons-lang.version>3.4</commons-lang.version>    
        <commons-csv.version>1.2</commons-csv.version>
        <log4j.version>2.4.1</log4j.version>
        <postgresql-jdbc.version>9.1-901.jdbc4</postgresql-jdbc.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.0.5.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate-validator.version>5.2.2.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
        <javax-el-api.version>2.2.4</javax-el-api.version>
        <hibernate-search.version>5.5.1.Final</hibernate-search.version>
        <simmetrics.version>4.0.1</simmetrics.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Commons CSV -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-csv.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons Lang -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>${log4j.version}</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
        <!--HIBERNATE LOGGER (log4j)-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Old JDBC4 for PostgreSQL 9.1 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql-jdbc.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency><!-- Core -->
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency><!-- c3p0 -->
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency><!-- postgis/spatial -->
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency><!-- hibernate validator -->
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
                <version>${javax-el-api.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
        <dependency><!-- hibernate search -->
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-search.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-search.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mpkorstanje</groupId>
            <artifactId>simmetrics-core</artifactId>
            <version>${simmetrics.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Do somebody know why am I getting this weird error?

**EDIT**:

As requested, I'll post the entire class and superclass.

- AbstractDAO:

  ```
  package dao;

  import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
  import org.hibernate.Session;
  import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
  import org.hibernate.Transaction;
  import org.hibernate.search.FullTextSession;
  import org.hibernate.search.Search;
  import org.hibernate.search.SearchFactory;
  import org.hibernate.stat.Statistics;

  public abstract class AbstractDao {

      private Session currentSession;
      private Transaction currentTransaction;
      private SessionFactory factory;

      private Statistics stats;

      /**
       * Hibernate Search Engine
       */
      private FullTextSession fullTextSession = null;
      private SearchFactory searchFactory = null;

      protected AbstractDao(){
          factory = getSessionFactory();
      }

      public Session openCurrentSession() throws HibernateException {
          if(currentSession == null || !currentSession.isOpen())
              currentSession = factory.openSession();
          return currentSession;
      }

      public Session openCurrentSessionwithTransaction() throws HibernateException {
          if(currentSession == null || !currentSession.isOpen())
              currentSession = factory.openSession();
          currentTransaction = currentSession.beginTransaction();
          return currentSession;
      }

      public void closeCurrentSession() {
          currentSession.close();
      }

      public void closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction() {
          currentTransaction.commit();
          currentSession.close();
      }

      protected abstract SessionFactory getSessionFactory() throws HibernateException;

      public Session getCurrentSession() {
          return currentSession;
      }

      public void setCurrentSession(Session currentSession) {
          this.currentSession = currentSession;
      }

      public Transaction getCurrentTransaction() {
          return currentTransaction;
      }

      public void setCurrentTransaction(Transaction currentTransaction) {
          this.currentTransaction = currentTransaction;
      }

      public void commitTransaction(){
          if(currentTransaction != null)
              currentTransaction.commit();
      }

      public void rollbackTransaction(){
          if(currentTransaction != null)
              currentTransaction.rollback();
      }

      /**

          @return the factory
       */
      public SessionFactory getFactory() {
          return factory;
      }

      /**

          @param factory the factory to set
       */
      public void setFactory(SessionFactory factory) {
          this.factory = factory;
      }

      /**

          @return the stats
       */
      public Statistics getStats() {
          return stats;
      }

      /**

          @param stats the stats to set
       */
      public void setStats(Statistics stats) {
          this.stats = stats;
      }

      /**

          @return the fullTextSession
       */
      public FullTextSession getFullTextSession() {
          return fullTextSession;
      }

      /**

          @param fullTextSession the fullTextSession to set
       */
      public void setFullTextSession(FullTextSession fullTextSession) {
          this.fullTextSession = fullTextSession;
      }

      protected SearchFactory getHibernateSearch(){
          if(fullTextSession == null){
              fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(getCurrentSession());
          }
          if(searchFactory == null){
              searchFactory = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory();
          }
          return searchFactory;
      }

      /**

          @return the searchFactory
       */
      public SearchFactory getSearchFactory() {
          return searchFactory;
      }

      /**

          @param searchFactory the searchFactory to set
       */
      public void setSearchFactory(SearchFactory searchFactory) {
          this.searchFactory = searchFactory;
      }

      public void finish() throws Throwable{
          Session session = getCurrentSession();
          if(session != null)
              session.close();
          if(factory != null)
              factory.close();
      }

  }
  ```
- ServiceDAOParadasWS class:

  ```
  package dao.paradasws;

  import java.util.List;

  import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
  import org.hibernate.Criteria;
  import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
  import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
  import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
  import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
  import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
  import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
  import org.hibernate.search.FullTextQuery;
  import org.hibernate.search.FullTextSession;
  import org.hibernate.search.SearchFactory;
  import org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.QueryBuilder;

  import dao.AbstractDao;
  import model.paradasws.OperadorWS;
  import model.paradasws.ParadaWS;

  public class ServiceDaoParadasWs extends AbstractDao implements IDaoParadasWs {

      public ServiceDaoParadasWs(){
          super();
      }

      @Override
      protected SessionFactory getSessionFactory() throws HibernateException {
          // already posted
      }

      @Override
      public List<ParadaWS> getParadas() {
          openCurrentSession();
          @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
          List<ParadaWS> paradasWs = (List<ParadaWS>) getCurrentSession().createQuery("from ParadaWS").list();

          return paradasWs;
      }

      @Override
      public List<ParadaWS> getParadaPorNombre(String pDescripcionCorta, OperadorWS pOperador) {
          openCurrentSession();

          Criteria c = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(ParadaWS.class);
          c.add(
              Restrictions.and(
                      Restrictions.eq("descripcionCorta", pDescripcionCorta).ignoreCase(),
                      Restrictions.eq("operador", pOperador)
              )
          );

          @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
          List<ParadaWS> paradas = c.list();

          return paradas;
      }

      @Override
      public OperadorWS getOperador(Integer pId) {
          openCurrentSession();
          Criteria c = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(OperadorWS.class);//createQuery("from OperadorWS op where op.codigoOperador=:id");
          c.add(Restrictions.eq("codigoOperador", pId));

          OperadorWS op = (OperadorWS) c.uniqueResult();

          return op;
      }

      public void indexarParadas(){
          openCurrentSession();
          getHibernateSearch();
          FullTextSession txtSession = getFullTextSession();
          txtSession.getTransaction().begin();
          @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
          List<ParadaWS> paradas = txtSession.createQuery("from ParadaWS").list();
          for (ParadaWS paradaWS : paradas) {
              txtSession.index(paradaWS);
          }
          txtSession.getTransaction().commit();
      }

      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      public List<ParadaWS> buscarSimilitudesNombreParada(String pNombreCorto){
          openCurrentSession();
          SearchFactory fact = getHibernateSearch();
          FullTextSession txtSession = getFullTextSession();
          QueryBuilder b = fact.buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(ParadaWS.class).get();

          Query query = b.keyword()
              .fuzzy()
                  .withEditDistanceUpTo(2)
              .onField("descripcionCorta")
              .matching(pNombreCorto)
              .createQuery();

          FullTextQuery txtQuery = txtSession.createFullTextQuery(query, ParadaWS.class);

          return (List<ParadaWS>) txtQuery.list();

      }

  }
  ```

Note that the implementor of AbstractDAO must override getSessionFactory() method (the exception is caused here).

Comment: Please add the exception message to the question.  Don't just post a link to the output log.

Comment: Do you have any Initializer into your class? I'd suggest you post it. The error comes from there apparently.

Comment: @YassinHajaj what do you mean with Initializer? This project is built in a jar file, which has a Main class. This main class makes calls to one my databases' Service layer (which owns the getSessionFactory() method I've posted).

Comment: [Here is a definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) I'd suggest to post the entire class to look after initialization blocks. It seems the problem comes from there.

Comment: I would guess that you are missing a JAR on your standalone classpath which exists on the Eclipse launch classpath. You know that you can look at the effective command line of a running application in Eclipse by right clicking on the application in the debug view and choosing _Properties_?

Comment: @TobiasLiefke thanks! I've got it and I'm gonna analyse it :)

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the Hibernate Search *service* was not found on the classpath when the Hibernate ORM *SessionFactory* was started.

The classes seem to be there (as you have a *org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver* successfully loaded in your stacktrace).

So I could guess that the *maven-assembly-plugin* plugin is failing to include the service definitions from the Hibernate Search jars.

Specifically, it looks like you're missing these definitions from ***META-INF/services/*** :

- https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/tree/5.5.1.Final/orm/src/main/resources/META-INF/services

I'm not familiar enough with those Maven plugins to be able to suggest you how it should be configured, but I'd assume it could work with a different configuration.

I would suggest to try getting it to work fist without attempting to repackage it all: using a plain classpath with the original jars we released should just work.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply, but the META-INF/services/ folder is within, filled with those 3 classes and much more. Perhaps I should take a look at maven assembly plugin...

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to export an executable JAR which works...

In Eclipse, right click over your project; Export; select Runnable JAR file; choose your Launch configuration, export destination (something like myfile.jar), select Package required libraries into generated JAR and press Finish.

I don't know why, but this way isn't giving me any error and I can execute it. Well, to be honest there's one thing it isn't working: log4j2, this is, logs aren't created. If I move log4j2.xml file from /resources to /, logs are created.